# Avoiding inheritance of submenu items in CSS superfish menu

Tags: css, superfish

I need some more help on my superfish menu here:
http://web288.merkur.ibone.ch/klingler/

I would like to modify the main buttons on hover and current. However this does also change the submenu entries what I do not want. I am not a CSS expert but somehow the submenu entries do inherit the properties. What I tried to add is the following

```
.sf-menu a:hover,
.sf-menu li.current a,
.sf-menu li.sfHover a {
    background: #e24c4c url(../../images/bg-top-a-active.png) no-repeat center bottom;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    border-radius: 5px;
```

}

This does what I want for the main buttons but it does also change the submenu entries... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you only want to select the a elements which are direct children of li.current or li.sfHover.

```
.sf-menu a:hover,
.sf-menu li.current > a,
.sf-menu li.sfHover > a {
```

Comment: Close, only that the 'current' item in the submenu gets changed. See "Produktportfolio" menu: http://web288.merkur.ibone.ch/klingler/

Comment: So you only want the `a` element which is a direct children of `li.current`, which is a direct children of the navigation-root-ul element. Now that you know the `>` combinator, where is your problem with that?

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not understand what you are saying. This may be due to my limited css knowledge. Can you see that the hover of the submenus are not doing what they should?

Comment: I am doing a bit of try and error here as I do not know how the `>` works... Now it looks better, however the menu entries without submenus do no longer react on hover...

Comment: You changed `.sf-menu a:hover` to `.sf-menu > a:hover`. There is no such element. `.sf-menu > li > a:hover` is probably what you want.